# How to install older version of Firefox on AWS (Ubuntu)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, selenium, firefox

I'm trying to use an older version of Firefox on AWS (running selenium, 55 isn't compatible) but I haven't had any luck. When I try to download the compressed older files, I get

```
(firefox:6186): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
/usr/bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally without any error message
```

Any ways to fix this/alternate ways to download?

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue with firefox when I was running selenium project with it. I did the following things that helped me. First uninstall the firefox by using command,

```
 sudo apt-get remove --purge firefox
```

Some of the old files could also be there, you need to remove them manually.
Then you can install the previous version from the link provided below which shows list of all previous versions of the firefox, version 54, works fine for selenium.

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/install-older-version-of-firefox

When you install it, Mozilla build for Firefox would be opened as a browser and you can perform selenium tests there. 
Hope this helps!